# How to choose object from list and print its name

Tags: python, class, object

I have class Something with few objects:

```
class Something():
def __init__(self,  name, attr1, attr2):
    self.name= name
    self.attr1= attr1
    self.attr2= attr2

def getName(self):
    return self.name

Obj1=Something('Name1',  'bla bla1',  'bla bla2') 
Obj2=Something('Name2',  'bla bla3',  'bla bla4')
```

Those objects are stored in list:

```
objects = [Obj1, Obj2]
```

I want to select object from the printed list and then (if object is on the list) print its name.
So far I wrote code below, but it doesn't work. with error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getNazwa')

```
print('Select object from list: ', objects)
y=raw_input('enter the name of the object')

for i in objects:
    if y == i:
        print "Name: " + i.getName()
```

When print list it's someting like that:

```
('Select object fromfrom list: ', [<__main__.Something instance at 0x024FB440>, <__main__.Something instance at 0x024FB490>])
```

How to convert it into print objects name?

I guess that solution isn't rocket science for You Guys, so someone will help me ;)

Comment: use `if y == i.name:`

Comment: Your code sample doesn't use `getNazwa` anywhere. The code posted here won't throw any exception (once we correct for the indentation error in the class definition). Please include a *full traceback* of the error.

Comment: for some reason `i` is considered as a string, you sure you have a list of class `objects` and not `strings`?

Comment: If it would be list of strings, how print object name with the same name as list item?

Comment: well, if you have the Object name as string, you can use `eval()` function to get the desired output, for e.g `eval(i).getName()`, however this is not recommended every time as `eval()` is considered bad practice and dangerous to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that you compare string to an object here:

```
if y == i:
```

so you should either look at `__eq__` method of your class, or compare input string with obj name like:

```
if y == i.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

in your lines:

```
for i in objects:
    if y == i:
```

i is an object, and y in a string, so you can't compare them

however, you can do

```
for i in objects:
    if y == i.getName():
```

so you compare two strings together